# Android difference between slog vs androi.util.log logging

Tags: android

In my Android app, I am trying to implement logger. While doing so I see Android packages use slog, and I see there is `Log` under `android.util` package, which is being used widely in the application, see below code:

Slog

```
 Slog.v(TAG, "onCreate " + this + ": " + savedInstanceState)
```

Log

```
Log.v(TAG, e.printStackTrace())
```

what is difference between the above logs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For future readers of this post, [**`Slog`**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-release/core/java/android/util/Slog.java) is simply a *wrapper* over the standard [`android.util.Log`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-release/core/java/android/util/Log.java) which *logs* its output under the [`Log.LOG_ID_SYSTEM`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/Log.java#370) id.

There are [five different IDs](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-release/core/java/android/util/Log.java#363) under which the logs are categorized and those are:

- [`LOG_ID_MAIN`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-release/core/java/android/util/Log.java#363): For the *main* buffer under which all *common* application logs go.
- [`LOG_ID_SYSTEM`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-release/core/java/android/util/Log.java#366): For the system log buffer where all system services logs.
- [`LOG_ID_RADIO`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-release/core/java/android/util/Log.java#364): For logging radio-related events.
- [`LOG_ID_EVENTS`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-release/core/java/android/util/Log.java#365): For logging system and sensor events.
- [`LOG_ID_CRASH`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-release/core/java/android/util/Log.java#367): For logging crashes and `wtf` failures

[image: Android Logging]

Image source: https://elinux.org/Android_Logging_System